# CSS margin & padding not working

Tags: css, pdf

When I convert html to PDF margin & padding are not applied in PDF.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" style="width:40px; height:40px;margin-top: -23px; margin-left: -6px;">
    </td>
    <td width="85%" valign="bottom">
        <font size="4" face="Arial"><b>Happy to help</b></font>
        <hr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, how to reduce height of `hr` element?

[image: hr screenshot]

[image: pdf with hr screenshot]

Comment: Use `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to spacing between `td`

Comment: Try avoiding negative pixel values..

Comment: Which tool are you using to convert the HTML to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.styleHr{
border-top: 0px solid #8c8b8b;

}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" style="width:40px; height:40px;margin-top: -23px; margin-left: -6px;">
    </td>
    <td width="85%" valign="bottom">
        <font size="4" face="Arial"><b>Happy to help</b></font>
        <hr class="styleHr">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Use a class to hr and apply styles for that class.

Comment: Inline css not applied in PDF

Comment: Are you trying to print the pdf? in that case try @media print option

Comment: No i am converting html to PDF in php

Comment: Try giving it in % instead of px.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this and let me know

<tr>
        <td style="display: block;">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" style="display: block; width:40px; height:40px; margin-top: 23px; margin-left: 6px;">
        </td>
        <td width="85%" valign="bottom">
            <font size="4" face="Arial"><b>Happy to help</b></font>
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please see second image bottom of my question(enter image description here) I want this design on PDF